# Can't delete files because I'm not the owner

Tags: delete, ownership

I am building a PC and my father had an old drive laying around, but there are files on it. My father has a PC with Ubuntu on it. (I don't know how Ubuntu works.) I hooked up the drive to his PC to delete the files, so I selected the files, but when I pressed Delete nothing happened. I right clicked but it didn't say Delete. When I pressed properties it said "You are not the owner of this drive".

I'm going to install Windows. Will it delete all files?

Comment: keep all those files in a folder , then execute this command    from terminal -->sudo chmod  -r  744  <path of the folder to be deleted>

Comment: @AkhilVarma: Why not directly `sudo rm -r <PATH>`?

Comment: Why don't you just reformat the disk during install?

Comment: @DavidFoerster: he doesn't have privileges to delete those files, that's why.

Comment: @AkhilVarma: Yeah, but if he can run `sudo` then he can just delete the files right away instead of first widening their access permissions. If he can't run `sudo` then he can't widen access permissions anyway.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: yes , that's a valid point mr. foerster.

Answer (score 3):

When you install Windows, delete all the partitions on the disk. This will effectively delete all the files.